# How to refresh state of image path in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hello I have found how to display a taken picture from camera, but first to display I need to reload the app and same for remove picture. Changed are visible only if I reload the app and not directly after action ( onPressed button ).

Here is my code:

```dart
Future<String> picture() async {
final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    setState(() {
        if ( imagePath!= null){
        imagePath="${extDir.path}/Pictures/$daysfromnow_modify.jpg";
        }
    });
}
```

To display image from path I use: `Image.file(new File(imagePath),),`.

Here is the part where I increase or decrease `$daysfromnow_modify`.

```dart
new IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_left),
    iconSize: 30.0,
    color: Colors.black,
    onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
            changedate--;

            DateTime now = DateTime.now();
            final _dateFormatter = DateFormat.yMMMMd("fr_FR");
            DateTime daysfromnow = now.add(new Duration(days: changedate));

            formattedDate = _dateFormatter.format(daysfromnow);


            RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r"(^\S*)"); // Here is the regex fonction to extract long, lat
            var match = regExp.firstMatch("$daysfromnow");
            daysfromnow_modify = match.group(1);
        });
    }
)
```

I call `picture()` at the init, when I increase or decrease `$daysfromnow_modify` to switch next or previous photo and I call him also when I remove the path. For all this call I expect a refresh of stats but nothing.

Comment: What do you want? you didn't tell that

Comment: @Muhammad Noman When I change path of image ( incrase or decrease $daysfromnow_modify with help of button), images isn't reload, the image change only if I reload completly the app and not when I call picture() after pressed button.

Comment: change this ```imagePath="${extDir.path}/Pictures/$daysfromnow_modify.jpg";``` to this ```imagePath="${extDir.path}/Pictures/${daysfromnow_modify}.jpg";```

Comment: I tried, but no change... After picture take I have place a print("$imagpath") to verify that the function is call and that imagepath is good, and the function is call with good path... but seems that  Image.file(new File(imagePath),), was not rebuild after path modification

Comment: `prefs.setString('daysfromnow_modify',daysfromnow_modify)??"";` this code sets new value of `daysfromnow_modify` to key `daysfromnow_modify` in shared_preferences not to get it. You can get the value through `var val = prefs.getString("daysfromnow_modify") ?? "no value";`

Comment: @Shady Boshra well seen, but no influence. it was an oversight on my part, I can remove this line.

Comment: So then, wherevs the part of your code that the value of variable is changing?, if you can provide some codes..

Comment: I have upload the code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `picture()` method is called in the init and not during rendering/`build`. Because of that, the value of `imagePath` is not reactive based on `daysfromnow`. You can fix this by calling `picture()` any time `daysfromnow` is changed.